# Spring JMX Notification: Warning: Failed to deserialize a notification

Tags: spring, jmx

I am getting warning message from JConsole which is shown each time when my application sends the notification to the registered Spring MBean server.

I am getting my hands on using JMX with Spring 3.0. 
I have registered my ServiceImpl class as a MBean server. Here is my configuration

```
<!-- MBean Server Factory -->
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
 <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"></property>
 <property name="agentId" value="MMAC-056_1306399012572"></property>
</bean>

<!-- this bean must not be lazily initialized if the exporting is to happen -->
<bean id="exporter" 
class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
<property name="beans">
<map>
   <entry key="bean:name=searchCampaignService" value-ref="campaignService" />
</map>
</property>
<property name="server" ref="mbeanServer"></property>
<property name="autodetect" value="true"></property>
<property name="registrationBehaviorName" value="REGISTRATION_REPLACE_EXISTING" />
<property name="assembler">
<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler
                                               .MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler">
<property name="managedMethods">
    <value>searchCampaignById</value>
</property>
</bean>
</property>
<property name="notificationListenerMappings">
<map>
    <entry key="bean:name=searchCampaignService">
        <bean class="com....TestLoggingNotificationHandler" />
    </entry>
</map>
</property>

</bean>
```

My serviceimpl class implements NotificationPublisherAware interface & I am sending notification from one of my service methods that is exposed as a managed method. I want to test the notification locally first.

I can also see the JConsole displaying the bean with operation & notification nodes. 
I subscribe to notification & run my client application.
As soon as I run my client app the JConsole displays warning stating that

```
May 26, 2011 4:53:41 AM ClientNotifForwarder NotifFetcher.fetchOneNotif
WARNING: Failed to deserialize a notification: java.io.NotSerializableException:   

org.springframework.jmx.export.notification.ModelMBeanNotificationPublisher
```

I made my service & UserDataObject as serializable.. I also tried passing string to

```
notification.setUserData("Test notification"+ctr);
```

but still JConsole keeps on displaying the warning.

Comment: Most possibly the objects you notify is not an MBean and that is why it can't be deserialized by client. Because the object type is onknown.

Answer (score 0):

Manish;

Based on the error message you supplied, JConsle is unable to deserialize the notification because it contains a reference to an instance of **org.springframework.jmx.export.notification.ModelMBeanNotificationPublisher** which I assume is unintentional. Can you post the code that sends the notification ?

Answer (score 0):

While sending notification the Notification object you create should have source property which is instance of `MBean/MXBean`. Because, for JMX clients (such as JConsole and others) only these objects are known and serializable.

So, if you are sending this notification inside your MBean instance just use `this` as source in your Notification class.

```
 public class NotificationManager extends 
       NotificationBroadcasterSupport implements 
             **NotificationManagerMXBean** {

 private AtomicInteger sequence = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public void initialize() {
    this.sendNotification(new Notification("Initialization",
     **this**,sequence.incrementAndGet()));

}
```

Sending notification with more detail can be achieved with following type of notification. You can serialize object yourself ,i.e. JSon serialization.

```
this.sendNotification(
      new Notification("New", this
          , sequence.incrementAndGet(), 
            Instant.now().toEpochMilli(), myJSONSeiazedObject*));
```